# Subversive: cannot see version control visuals in Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm using the Subversive plugin for accessing an SVN server with Eclipse JavaEE. Although my project is well versionned, in the Package Explorer panel, I fail to see the yellow icon on the items, nor the version number on the right of the file name or anything.

I have the same configuration on another Eclipse (Java classic) and it works fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations` and make sure `SVN` is checked.

Look in `Preferences > Team > SVN > Label Decorations` and check which SVN decorations are enabled.